# Get list of available methods

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug

Is there a way to provide a list of available methods in `Watch` section during xdebug debugging? Take a look at the gif below:

[image: xdebug_vscode_watch]

What I'm getting here is an instance of an object that is part of array at `$variables['head_title']['head']`. It's type of `Drupal\Core\Render\Markup`. This object has some methods or properties defined, but I've no idea about names of these methods.

As you can see I used `count()` method and I got number of characters used. But, I'd like to get list of methods immediately after accessing this variables in watch section. So when I start typing `$variables['head_title']['head']->` it'll provide a list of methods to choose from.

The thing is there's no easy way to get it. It tells me what the name of class instance I'm getting, but there's no link to definition of the class, there's no list of available methods or properties, nothing. I need to manually walk through the dirs/files open this class and investigate methods available.

But this isn't really helpful as this class can inherit several times by other classes and it's really difficult to get full list of methods available for this instance. I know that PhpStorm has that kind of functionality, but is it possible in VSCode?

Comment: [ReflectionClass](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) and a bit of extra code to get list the methods at runtime. That's if you are after seeing what methods it has *(this comment is NOT about making code completion popup there .. which is what you are really after as I now understand, after re-reading your post few times)*

Comment: *"I know that phpstorm has that kind of functionality, but is it possible in vscode?"* It just a code completion functionality supplied in that input element. It will provide the same entries as in the file opened in the Editor (it shows what PhpStorm knows about that variable)

Comment: that's a really good start, now I can get the list of methods and much more, thanks a lot, it doesn't give an option to browse using autocompletion, but it certainly provides a list of methods or properties, which is great, thanks a lot